# How to add column with the next job of the same person?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table:

| employee number | job | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | paramedic | 2022 |
| 111 | doctor | 2021 |
| 111 | student | 2020 |
| 222 | waiter | 2022 |
| 222 | student | 2021 |
| 333 | nurse | 2022 |

I want to add one more column that will show what will be the next job of the same employee.
This is will be the result:

| employee number | job | year | next job |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | paramedic | 2022 | last job |
| 111 | doctor | 2021 | paramedic |
| 111 | student | 2020 | doctor |
| 222 | waiter | 2022 | last job |
| 222 | student | 2021 | waiter |
| 333 | nurse | 2022 | last job |

Comment: Use the `LAG(job) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_number ORDER BY year)` or `LEAD(job) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_number ORDER BY year DESC)` analytic functions.

Comment: How to change the null cells to last job?

Comment: Use the `COALESCE` function.

Comment: but how i connect it to the previous code that you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function LAG for this

```
SELECT
"employee number", "job", "year",
COALESCE(LAG("job") OVER(PARTITION BY "employee number" ORDER BY "year" DESC),' ') As Last_Job
FROM table1
```

| employee number | job | year | LAST_JOB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | paramedic | 2022 |  |
| 111 | doctor | 2021 | paramedic |
| 111 | student | 2020 | doctor |
| 222 | waiter | 2022 |  |
| 222 | student | 2021 | waiter |
| 333 | nurse | 2022 |  |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/U4-UdT4s)

Comment: How to change the null cells to last job?

Comment: sure add a COALESCE and add the ext you want

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that this is your table:

```
SQL> select * from employee order by empno, year desc;

     EMPNO JOB             YEAR NEXT_JOB
---------- --------- ---------- --------------------
       111 paramedic       2022
       111 doctor          2021
       111 student         2020
       222 waiter          2022
       222 student         2021
       333 nurse           2022

6 rows selected.
```

Update `next_job` by using the `LEAD` analytic function:

```
SQL> merge into employee a
  2    using (select empno,
  3                  year,
  4                  lead(job) over (partition by empno order by year) next_job
  5           from employee
  6          ) b
  7    on (a.empno = b.empno and a.year = b.year)
  8    when matched then update set
  9      a.next_job = b.next_job;

6 rows merged.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from employee order by empno, year desc;

     EMPNO JOB             YEAR NEXT_JOB
---------- --------- ---------- --------------------
       111 paramedic       2022
       111 doctor          2021 paramedic
       111 student         2020 doctor
       222 waiter          2022
       222 student         2021 waiter
       333 nurse           2022

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: How to change the null cells to last job?

Comment: Use NVL or COALESCE function; modify line #9 to `a.next_job = nvl(b.next_job, a.job);`